# Undefined variable $variable

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason this line of code returns `  "message": "Undefined variable $activeTargetValue",
I'm wondering why? even though I did a check if activeTarget is_null but didn't work

```php
$activeTarget = CustomerServiceTarget::with('target', 'target.target_type')->where("customer_service_id", auth()->user()->CustomerService->id)->ActiveTarget()->get();
    foreach ($activeTarget as $activeTargetValue)
        $target['amount'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->amount;
        $target['name'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->target_type->name; // here

        $contactedCustomersActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() : 0;
        $contactedCustomersTarget = 0;
        if (false !== $contactedCustomersKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["ContactedCustomers"], $target['name']))
            $contactedCustomersTarget = $target['amount'][$contactedCustomersKey];

        $usedCouponsActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() : 0;
        $usedCouponsTarget = 0;
        if (false !== $usedCouponsKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["UsedCoupons"], $target['name']))
            $usedCouponsTarget = $target['amount'][$usedCouponsKey];

    .. return statement
```

Comment: For which line exactly you get this message?

Comment: just edited my question, kindly check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use brackets like this:

```php
foreach ($activeTarget as $activeTargetValue) {
            $target['amount'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->amount;
            $target['name'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->target_type->name; // here

            $contactedCustomersActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() : 0;
            $contactedCustomersTarget = 0;
            if (false !== $contactedCustomersKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["ContactedCustomers"], $target['name']))
                $contactedCustomersTarget = $target['amount'][$contactedCustomersKey];

            $usedCouponsActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() : 0;
            $usedCouponsTarget = 0;
            if (false !== $usedCouponsKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["UsedCoupons"], $target['name']))
                $usedCouponsTarget = $target['amount'][$usedCouponsKey];
}
```

When you dont use brackets, it will be like this:

```php
foreach ($activeTarget as $activeTargetValue) {
        $target['amount'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->amount;
}
        $target['name'][] = $activeTargetValue->target->target_type->name; // here

        $contactedCustomersActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::contacted()->count() : 0;
        $contactedCustomersTarget = 0;
        if (false !== $contactedCustomersKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["ContactedCustomers"], $target['name']))
            $contactedCustomersTarget = $target['amount'][$contactedCustomersKey];

        $usedCouponsActual = CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() > 0 ? CustomerProcedurePulled::usedCoupons()->count() : 0;
        $usedCouponsTarget = 0;
        if (false !== $usedCouponsKey = array_search(TargetType::TARGET_TYPE["UsedCoupons"], $target['name']))
            $usedCouponsTarget = $target['amount'][$usedCouponsKey];
```

Comment: still gives error `Undefined variable $contactedCustomersActual"`

Comment: In which line??

Comment: when returning $contactedCustomersActual below the closure of the brackets

Comment: because you difine `$contactedCustomersActual` in this scope, write `$contactedCustomersActual = null;` out of the scope and then try it

Comment: You're welcome, if my answer helped you with your question, I would appreciate it if you upvote my answer and choose it as the best answer as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

PHP blocks should be surrounded by curly Brackets (`{}`):

```
foreach ($activeTarget as $activeTargetValue) {
   :
}
```

If you don use brackets, the default behavior is that only the first line is inside your `foreach` block.

In general, it is a bad practice to use blocks in PHP without brackets.